# Continue executing the function

Tags: jquery, slide, mouseenter, continue

I adapted a jQuery / Slide to execute the function when you hover over a button, so far everything right. Now we just need to continue to run the function with the mouse over the button and not only run 1 time.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#next-column').mouseenter(function(next) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.table-container').animate({scrollLeft:'+=438'}, 'slow');
});
$('#previous-column').mouseenter(function(prev) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.table-container').animate({scrollLeft:'-=438'}, 'slow');        
});
});
});
</script>

<a id="previous-column" href="#"><img src="images/b-prev.png"></a>
<a id="next-column" href="#"><img src="images/b-next.png"></a>
```

Can anyone help? I'm googling but have not found how to do this. 
 
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Please attach a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of your code to demonstrate your problem. Also, is there a reason you're wrapping `$(document).ready()` inside `$(window).load()`?

Comment: There is a problem in the code, I just want to continue to execute code when the mouse is the button, currently only runs 1 time. Thanks.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/insideinside/ejA5w

Comment: I wish when mousing Next in Jquery execute continuously to go through the pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add a timeout for mouseenter event and do a looping for scrollLeft or scrollRight like this

```
var timeout;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#next-column').hover(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        scrollLeft()
    }, function () {
        clearTimeout(timeout)
    });
    $('#previous-column').hover(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        scrollRight()
    }, function () {
        clearTimeout(timeout)
    });
});

function scrollLeft() {
    $('.table-container').animate({scrollLeft:'+=152'}, 'slow');
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){scrollLeft()}, 1000)
}
function scrollRight() {
    $('.table-container').animate({scrollLeft:'-=152'}, 'slow');
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){scrollRight()}, 1000)
}
```

### Edit

here's the right one : [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ejA5w/4/), I just see why it only appear until 5 row because I forgot to change the css, it should work fine now

Comment: Strangely your code works only 2 times then to only pass the slides and.

Comment: can you explain it more by "only 2 times then to only pass the slides and"

Comment: Can not stop, must continue to show the slides. See that your code has 10 divs but when mousing Next only shows 2 slides and.

Comment: if your problem is solved, please mark as your accepted answer, so other that come with the same problem could know what to do :)

Comment: Just one more question, how do I go back to be with and not click with mouse hover?

Comment: what did you mean with 'how do I go back to be with and not click with mouse hover?', I don't really get what you mean. Did you mean 'how do I change it back to be working with click and not with mouse hover?'